# Access all model from associated models callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Question model with a callback:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :qtags
  has_many :tags, through: :qtags

  after_save { self.tags.find_or_create(self) }
end
```

This passes the question to Tag which should create some tags from the tag_list

In the tag.rb I would like to access all tags to check if one already exists:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :qtags
  has_many :questions, through: :qtags

  def self.find_or_create(question)
    question.tags.destroy_all
    question.tag_list.split(' ').each do |tag|
      # Tag.where here can't access all the tags, just the associated ones.
      if Tag.where(name: tag).exists? && question.tags.ids.exclude?(Tag.where(name: tag).first.id)
        question.tags << Tag.where(name: tag)
      elsif Tag.where(name: tag).blank?
        question.tags << Tag.create(name: tag)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However this only checks in the tags which have the associated questions id.

so, when I add a pry console with binding.pry:

```
     5: def self.find_or_create(question)
     6:   question.tags.destroy_all
 =>  7:   binding.pry
     8:   question.tag_list.split(' ').each do |tag|
     9:     if Tag.where(name: tag).exists? && question.tags.ids.exclude?(Tag.where(name: tag).first.id)
    10:       question.tags << Tag.where(name: tag)
    11:     elsif Tag.where(name: tag).blank?
    12:       question.tags << Tag.create(name: tag)
    13:     end
    14:   end
    15: end

[1] pry(Tag)> Tag.all
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "qtags" ON "tags"."id" = "qtags"."tag_id" WHERE "qtags"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 11]]
```

It selects only the tags with the associated questions id.

How can I access all the tags with Tag.all or Tag.where(..) not just which have the caller questions id?

Comment: Where is `tag_name` defined?

Comment: question.tag_list gets split up to tag_names, but the qustion is, why Tag.all gets called with the questions id like: [question.id, 11], why can't I access all the tags?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand.  Can you add more of your code to your question?  The parts you've replaced with "..." for example.

Comment: Question is not clear, please add more input on this.

Comment: Question calls the Tag method to create the tags, but the method can't check if the tag already exists, cause it only gets the already associated tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem but I got around it like this:

Instead of using a callback I called the find_or_create method from the controller like this:

```
  def create
    Tag.find_or_create(@question) if @question.save
    respond_with(@question)
  end
```

**Edit:**

Now I see what was the error:

```
  after_save { self.tags.find_or_create(self) }
```

This should be:

```
  after_save { Tag.find_or_create(self) }
```